# Enum HWND properties c++

Tags: c++, winapi, hwnd

I am trying to get properties from an `HWND`.  I'm used information from [Using Window Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633561.aspx), but the example below is not working for me. I'm getting an error while compiling my code.

> argument of type "BOOL (__stdcall *)(HWND hwndSubclass, LPCSTR lpszString, HANDLE hData)" is incompatible with parameter of type "PROPENUMPROCEXW"

Here is my callback function

```
BOOL CALLBACK PropEnumProcEx(HWND hwndSubclass, LPCSTR lpszString, HANDLE hData) {
    return TRUE;
}
```

and this how I'm using it

```
EnumPropsEx(hwnd, PropEnumProcEx, NULL);
```

Does someone have any suggestions of how this can be fixed?

Comment: The error message couldn't be clearer. Do you understand it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`LPCSTR lpszString` should be `LPTSTR lpszString`. This argument should accept a pointer to either ANSI or Unicode null-terminated string. `PROPENUMPROCEXW` indicates that you are building Unicode application so `EnumPropsEx` macro expands to `EnumPropsExW` call so you need to provide callback accepting wide string as an argument. Typically you should always explicitly call Unicode variants of API functions.

Also you are missing last argument `ULONG_PTR dwData`.

So your callback should look like:

```
BOOL CALLBACK
PropEnumProcEx(HWND hwndSubclass, LPTSTR lpszString, HANDLE hData, ULONG_PTR dwData)
{
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: **−1** “`LPCSTR lpszString` should be `LPTSTR lpszString`” is very ungood advice. The `T` macros had their time between 1995 and 2000. In 2000 we got Layer for Unicode, making the macros obsolete. Today our tools can't even produce executables for the systems, Windows 9x, that the macros targeted. It's lunacy to continue using them for non-legacy code.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf It is acceptable if this code is supposed to be built in ANSI variant as well. And my answer contains suggestion to prefer using Unicode variants of API calls.

Comment: @VTT: Don't recommend building as ANSI. Some readers could take you seriously. Then you just make problems for them. Admit wrongdoing. Fix answer.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I didn't recommend building as ANSI anywhere.

Comment: @Cheers Please Be Nice.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: `EnumPropsEx` is a `TCHAR` based macro, so it is perfectly correct and reasonable to use `TCHAR` in the callback to match. If you don't want to support ANSI, don't use `TCHAR` APIs in the first place. In this case, use `EnumPropsExW` directly, and use `LPWSTR` in the callback.